# Cast from base class to different classes depending on one base field

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, casting

I have to implement the following pattern:

1. Base class contains just a variable that contains the type.
2. Program reads an XML into an XDocument from a list of files that have only a single node (type) in common. The rest of the nodes depend on the type.
3. XDocument is parsed into a **Chip** object.
4. Program has to check the **Chip** type field and cast it into the appropriate **ChipType** object so the rest of the properties and methods are available.

I played around a little with Interfaces and Inheritance, but I am not able to make my pattern work. Should you have any other simpler pattern to achieve something similar, please post it.

A rough example of what I need follows.

```
public class Chip
{
    //int variable for simplicity. I can use enum later. 
    public int FamilyType;

    public Chip(int Type)
    {
        FamilyType = Type;
    }
}

public class ChipType1 : Chip 
{
    /*Properties #1*/
    /*Methods #1*/
    public ChipType1() : base (1)
    {

    }
}

public class ChipType2 : Chip
{
    /*Properties #2*/
    /*Methods #2*/
    public ChipType2() : base (2)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind giving more context, specifically some example of what you want to do differently on each chip after cast? Casting from parent to child is explicitly forbidden in C# as far as I know, and is usually indicative of some design issue (though you may have a legitimate reason to want this I just can think of). Also checkout out [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I am building a compiler that translates a program from a specific language to another. The compilation/translation is depended on the Chip that is going to run the compiled code. So when I finish with the actual coding in my software, I have to choose from different kind of chips that are defined as XML files, before compiling.

Comment: But isn't the behavior the same? All have `next_instruction` or `clear_cache` or something like that?

Comment: @kabanus What do you mean by "behaviour"? The compiled code may be completely different depending on the chip (XML values).

Comment: I mean the functionality of all chips. Not the details of implementation. This translates to methods (the names) in your code.

Comment: At the moment I am using only two chips that have identical structures. So you could say "yes" for now. I need a more generic pattern though, because later I may have to expand the chip functionalities depending on type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late response. I ended up using an object variable. When I need to use it I check the type in a switch clause and cast the controller object to the respective class.

```
public class Chip
{
    //int variable for simplicity. I can use enum later. 
    public int FamilyType;
    public object Controller;

    public Chip(int Type)
    {
        FamilyType = Type;
        if (FamilyType == 1)
          Controller = new ChipType1();
        else if (FamilyType == 2)
          Controller = new ChipType2();
    }
}

public class ChipType1
{
    /*Properties #1*/
    /*Methods #1*/
    public ChipType1() 
    {

    }
}

public class ChipType2  
{
    /*Properties #2*/
    /*Methods #2*/
    public ChipType2()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You chip class should go like this

```
public class Chip<T>
{
    public T FamilyType;
}
public class ChipOne
{
    //properties
}
public class ChipTwo
{
    //properties
}
// If creating Chip of type ChipOne manually
var chip1 = new Chip<ChipOne>();
//Accessing some property
//chip1.FamilyType.someProperty
```

I hope this can help you. Parsing XML into the above class hierarchy should work

Comment: I cannot try your suggestion at the moment. I will post back later this day.